# file uploading through view model coming as null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, viewmodel

I have two view models as below

```
public class hdr_doc_upload
{
    public string document_name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase UpFile { get; set; }
}

public class list_doc
{
    public List<hdr_doc_upload> hdr_doc_upload { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create_Group()
{
    list_doc list = new list_doc();
    return View(list);
}
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hdr_doc_upload[0].document_name)
<input type="file" id="hdr_doc_upload[0].UpFile" name="hdr_doc_viewmodel[0].UpFile" />
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hdr_doc_upload[1].document_name)
<input type="file" id="hdr_doc_upload[1].UpFile" name="hdr_doc_viewmodel[1].UpFile" />
```

Give me below screen

[image]

but when i submit the page we only getting the textbox values the file is getting as null.
[image]

Comment: `name="hdr_doc_viewmodel[0].UpFile` has no relationship to your model (its `hdr_doc_upload`, not `hdr_doc_viewmodel`)

Comment: And generate it correctly using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.hdr_doc_upload[i].UpFile, new { type = "file" })` inside a `for` loop and add 2 items to you collection in the GET method

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually number of files will be dynamic..is it possible to create a button and generate the same dynamically?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for a couple of options

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your creating manual `<input>` elements that have `name` attributes that do not relate to your model. The attributes needs to be

```
name="hdr_doc_upload[0].UpFile" // not hdr_doc_viewmodel[0].UpFile
```

However, you should be generating you control for the file input correctly using the strongly typed `TextBoxFor()` method, inside a `for` loop.

In your controller, populate your model with 2 new instances of `hdr_doc_upload` before passing the model to the view

```
list_doc list = new list_doc()
{
    new list_doc(),
    new list_doc()
};
return View(list);
```

and then in the view

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hdr_doc_upload[i].document_name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hdr_doc_upload[i].UpFile, new { type = "file" })
}
```